# Example of a continuous bijective function on and to the closure of the complex numbers, with an inverse that is not continuous?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Note that by the closure of the complex number, I mean the union of the complex numbers and infinity.

I have been stumbling over this questions for a wile now, and I understand many examples of this for **subsets of the closure of the complex numbers**, but I wish to demonstrate it for the **closure of the complex numbers**.

I only know the very basics of topology, but is appear the **Invariance of Domain Theorem** implies that no such function would exist if this were for the **complex numbers** (rather than their closure).  So my questions are as follows:

1. Am I mistaken in the claim I made about the Invariance of Domain Theorem; if not, can this idea be extended is some way to the closure of the complex numbers?
2. Does such a function exist; and if so, what is an example?

(Please comment if my question is unclear, I will monitor regularly, and clarify anything if requested.)
(I apologize for not knowing how to typeset this.)

Comment: I added the general-topology tag, although maybe topologists will think of a more appropriate tag.  Also, it is best to make the question self-contained, so the kind of function you are asking about should be explained in the question body and not just in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a function can't exist, and this is an easier result than the invariance of domain.

The extended complex numbers form a compact Hausdorff space $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$.
In general, every closed subspace of a compact space is compact, every continuous image of a compact set is compact, and every compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.  Therefore if $f: \hat{\mathbb{C}} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is continuous, then it maps closed sets to closed sets.  If it is a bijection, then this means it also maps open sets to open sets, so $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: a continuous bijection between a compact space ($S^1$ as the compactification of $\mathbb C$) and a Hausdorff space-- $S^1$ again-- is automatically a homeomorphism, so that the inverse function is not just continuous, but an open and closed map.